# Having issues accessing data from my service in Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I'm trying to access and use the data from my service and having some issues. I am able to see the data returned just fine in the console from my `console.log(data);` from the method below:

```
public getCustomerData() {
      this.Service.getCustomers().subscribe((data) => {
      console.log(data);  
      this.customers = data.value;
      console.log(this.customers);
      var i:number;
      for(i = 0; i < this.customers.length; i++ ){
        if(this.customers[i].CityName == null || this.customers[i].StateName == null || this.customers[i].ZipCode == null || this.customers[i].Address1 == null){
          this.customers[i].Address1 = "";
          this.customers[i].CityName = "San Diego";
          this.customers[i].StateName = "California";
          this.customers[i].ZipCode = "12345";
        }

      }
    }) 
  }
```

Where I am running into issues is the next line `this.customers = data.value;`, I am recieving the error `Property 'value' does not exist on type 'Customer[]'.`

Here is how my data is returned:
[image]

Service method:

```
public getCustomers()
  {
    let url = "https://rss-staging.carefusion.com/api/odata/Facilities";
    const params = new HttpHeaders()
    .set('X-Atlas-SecurityKey', '75162FD1-A4E8-40AB-A62A-823932CEAD1F')

    return this.http.get<Customer[]>(url, {headers: params})
  }
```

HTML Table:

```
<div class="row pb-2">
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="input1">Name</label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Customer Name" class="form-control" id="input1"
                    aria-describedby="Text field" name="name" [(ngModel)]="fields.Name"
                    (ngModelChange)="updateFilters()" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-5">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="input1">Address</label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Customer Address" class="form-control" id="input1"
                    aria-describedby="Text field" name="address" [(ngModel)]="fields.Address1"
                    (ngModelChange)="updateFilters()" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row pb-2">
        <div class="col-lg-3">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="input1">City</label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="City" class="form-control" id="input1" aria-describedby="Text field"
                    name="city" [(ngModel)]="fields.CityName" (ngModelChange)="updateFilters()" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="input1">State</label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="State" class="form-control" id="input1" aria-describedby="Text field"
                    name="name" [(ngModel)]="fields.StateName" (ngModelChange)="updateFilters()" />
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="input1">Zip Code</label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="123456" class="form-control" id="input1" aria-describedby="Text field"
                    name="name" [(ngModel)]="fields.ZipCode" (ngModelChange)="updateFilters()" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Please share where you have defined `Service.getCustomers()`

Comment: @OwenKelvin added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the code, I can see that you have typecasted the result of the function `getCustomers()` to `customers[]`

```
 return this.http.get<Customer[]>(url, {headers: params})
```

Basically you are returning an array of customers from the http call.

To return correct value, pipe the results and map

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators'
 return this.http.get<any>(url, {headers: params}).pipe(
  map(data => data.value as Customer[])
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your method **getCustomers()** from the service already return a list of customers, and a list doesn't have a property called value.

You only have to do this, and should works.

```
this.customers = data;
```

Comment: When I try that, my table doesn't fill out at all. I think isn't mapped to customers correctly

Comment: Owen is right about the problem on his answer. I think that i will made something like on your service:
final response = await this.http.get<any>(url, {headers: params});
return (response as List).map((customer) => customer as Customer).toList();